# Retrieving file content using FTPClient Java

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons

Im using commons FTPCLIENT
I just want the file content from the ftp server. 
i dont want to write it to a temporary file.
Is there any way to do that.
The fileoutputstream  should always point to a local file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [FTPClientDemonstration ](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/Ftpclientdemonstration.htm)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`FTPClient.retrieveFileStream(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 4):

You should use retrieveFilestream method instead of retriveFile method..

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
// configuration code for ftpclient port, server etc
InputStream in = ftp.getretrieveFileStream("remoteFileName");
BufferedInputStream inbf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
int readCount;
byte result[] = null;
int length = 0;

while( (readCount = inbf.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      int preLength = length;
      length += readCount;
      byte temp[] = new byte[result.length];
      result = new byte[length];
      System.arraycopy(temp,0,result,0,temp.length); 
      System.arraycopy(buffer,0,result,preLength,readCount); 
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for the quick reply..

And that did work for me..
 this is what i tried .

-

```
 FTPclient fClient=new FTPclient(); 
   fClient.connect("server"); 
   Fclient.login("user","pwd"); 
      InputStream iStream=fClient.retrieveFileStream("file");
      BufferedInputStream bInf=new BufferedInputStream (iStream);
      int bytesRead;
     byte[] buffer=new byte[1024]; 
     String fileContent=null; 
   while((bytesRead=bInf.read(buffer))!=-1)
   {
       fileContent=new String(buffer,0,bytesRead); }


   enter code here
```