# How to convert FTPFIle to File using Java?

Tags: java, ftp-client

I need to read all the files from a shared location and returns a File Map. I use FTPClient to access the  shared location. Using FTPClient I able to retrieve all the File as a FTPFile. But I want Convert FTPFile to File. please see the code.

```
FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(folderPath);
```

Note:- **I Don't want to Create new connection every time. I want to read all in one connection**

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538230/retrieving-file-content-using-ftpclient-java

Comment: A `File` object represents a path to a file that may or may not exist. Do you really want to create `File` objects, or do you want to download the files to local disk?

Comment: I want to created a File object. I don't want to save the file.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is very old question but just wanted to update what I have done.

```
InputStream iStream=ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(ftpFile.getName());
File file = File.createTempFile("tmp", null);
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(iStream, file);
```

Hopefully this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want get the name, try this code:

```
private File[] getRemoteFilesInFolder() {
    FTPFile[] elements;
    File[] files;

    try {
        elements = ftpClient.listFiles();
        files = new File[elements.length];

        for(int i=0; i< elements.length; i++) {
            files[i] = new File(elements[i].getName());
        }
        return files;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```