# How to get files from FTPClient and convert into File?

Tags: java, file, ftp-client

I want to get files from FTPClient and convert FTPFiles into File. Why when I use this code, the (2nd, 3rd, 4th..) FtpFiles, they can't be converted into File, the Error is always NULL, only the 1st FTPFiles that success converted into File.

```
 FTPFile[] ftpFiles = client.listFiles();
            InputStream iStream;
            File file;
            for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles) {

                    System.out.printf(count+" FTPFile: %s; %s%n",
                            ftpFile.getName(),
                            FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(ftpFile.getSize()));
                    iStream = client.retrieveFileStream(ftpFile.getName());
                    file = File.createTempFile(ftpFile.getName(), null);
                    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(iStream, file);
                    System.out.println("cek File " + file.getName()+": "+FileUtils.sizeOf(file));

                }
```

Comment: please post your stacktrace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert FTPFIle to File using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311309/how-to-convert-ftpfile-to-file-using-java)

Comment: Yes, I have read of the solution on [How to convert FTPFIle to File using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311309/how-to-convert-ftpfile-to-file-using-java)  , and I have implement on the above code but still null when I convert into File (only1st FtpFile that success be converted).
This is my output console:

FTPFile: Embossing-06-09-2018.zip; 148 KB
cek File Embossing-06-09-2018.zip3714202227364091317.tmp: 152523
FTPFile: Embossing-10-09-2018.zip; 178 KB
2018-12-06 14:33:28.590 ERROR 16704 --- [tp1486944091-17] courier.bpm.EmbosOriServiceImpl  : null